# Column format datatool

Tags: tables, siunitx, datatool, mhchem

all. Suppose I have a csv file (let's call it data.csv):

```
Solution,mol/L,Volume(mL),delta_v(mL),moles
HNO3,16,5,0.2,3.125E-4
NaOH,6,20.2,0.2,3.367E-3
H2O,1;200,5,2.000E-1
H2SO4,6,5.2;0.2,8.667E-4
HCl,12,10;0.2,8.333E-4
```

Now, suppose I wanted to use the mhchem package and the siunitx package to help format different columns in data.csv. Specifically I'd like to wrap everything in the first column inside \ce{} (except the first row). So HNO3, would be \ce{HNO3} and thus would display with a subscripted 3. And I'd like to wrap everything in the moles column in \num{}.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

This is one way this could be done:

[image]

### Notes:

- As cgnieder suggested, one needs to use `\expandafter\ce\expandafter{\Solution}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Solution,mol/L,Volume(mL),delta_v(mL),moles
HNO3,16,5,0.2,3.125E-4
NaOH,6,20.2,0.2,3.367E-3
H2O,1,200,5,2.000E-1
H2SO4,6,5.2,0.2,8.667E-4
HCl,12,10,0.2,8.333E-4
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTable}[1]{% #1 = database
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c }% I think you mean \delta
        Solution & mol/L & Volume\,(mL) & $\Delta \textnormal{V}$\,(mL) & moles \\\hline%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{%
        \Solution=Solution,%
        \Mol=Mol,%
        \Volume=Volume,%
        \Delta=Delta,%
        \Moles=Moles%
        }{%
        \expandafter\ce\expandafter{\Solution} & \num{\Mol} & \num{\Volume} & \num{\Delta} & \num{\Moles}\\%
    }%
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[keys={Solution,Mol,Volume,Delta,Moles}]{myDB}{data.csv}

\PrintDTLTable{myDB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to expand `\Solution` first to satisfy `\ce`: `\expandafter\ce\expandafter{\Solution}`

Comment: `\ce` sort of looks through its input token by token before it decides what is an atom, a subscript, a stoichiometric factor,… also everything is typeset in mathmode (choosing `\mathrm` for atoms, I believe). If the input is not as `\ce` expects it is often displayed just like setting it between `$…$`. Not sure what happens without the `{}`. The input seems to be doubled and then the first token gobbled…